# Spoofed email: can't determine Purported Responsible Address

Tags: spoofing, smtp

I am studying the SMTP protocol and follow a course materials to setup a PoC spoofed email by talking with a SMTP server of our department.

This is what I have right now:

```
shuaiw@shuaicpu1:~$ telnet mail.XXXXXX 25
Trying XXX...
Connected to mail.XXX.hk.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 XXX ESMTP ; Mon, 4 Nov 2019 16:07:07 +0800
HELO random.org
250 XXX Hello 191host060.mobilenet.XXX [XXX], pleased to meet you
MAIL FROM: <test@random.org>
250 2.1.0 <test@random.org>... Sender ok
RCPT TO: <XXX@XXX>                      <---- this is a valid email address
250 2.1.5 <XXX@XXX>... Recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
this is the email body
.
550 5.7.1 can't determine Purported Responsible Address
```

I was expecting to send this message out but however, it returns `can't determine Purported Responsible Address`. Could anyone shed some lights on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> DATA
> 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
> this is the email body
> .
> ```

You don't send any mail header which also means that you don't send any `From` field in the mail header which means that server cannot extract `From` and use it for verification. See also [RFC 4407 - Purported Responsible Address in E-Mail Messages](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4407.txt).

Comment: I didn't get that. I do specify a `From` field, which is at `MAIL FROM: <test@random.org>`. Am I missed anything here? Thank you!

Comment: @lllllllllllll: *"I do specify a From field, which is at MAIL FROM: <test@random.org>"* - The MAIL FROM command in the SMTP protocol is not the `From` field in the mail header (which gets send within DATA). Please read RFC 5321 (SMTP) vs. RFC 5322 (Mail)